# ag grid floating filter mat select dropdown with multiple option checkbox not getting fliter results

Tags: angular, checkbox, filter, dropdown

Basically, in the current value, we are getting multiple options in form of the array but not able to filter it.

```js
this.params.onFloatingFilterChanged({ model: this.buildModel(this.currentValue) });
this.params.parentFilterInstance( (instance) => {
  if (typeof this.currentValue === 'object') {
    if (this.currentValue.length > 0) {
      **instance.onFloatingFilterChanged('equals', this.currentValue);//this.currentValue=['enable','disable']**
    } else {
      instance.onFloatingFilterChanged('equals', '');
    }
  } else {
    instance.onFloatingFilterChanged('equals', this.currentValue);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this.params.parentFilterInstance((instance) => {
      instance.setModel({ values: this.currentValue });
      this.params.api.onFilterChanged()
    });
```